# Could not deploy on Ropsten network using Truffle

Tags: web3js, truffle, contract-deployment, javascript, nodejs

I have following truffle-config.js file

```
const fs = require('fs');
const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const secrets = JSON.parse(
  fs.readFileSync("abc.txt").toString().trim()
);

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    ropsten: {
      provider: () =>
        new HDWalletProvider(
          secrets.seed,
          `https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/${secrets.projectId}`
        ),
      network_id: 3 
    }
  }
}
```

but when i run this command `truffle(develop)> migrate --reset --network ropsten`, i am facing following error;

```
Compiling your contracts...
===========================
> Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.

Unknown network "ropsten". See your Truffle configuration file for available networks.
```

in my abc.txt file i have

```
{
  "projectId": "7fb0bdc97cbe419fbdf9690......",
  "seed": "affair rally mail snake clever pony also hundred....."
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I know what the problem with this is, just in the place of `network_id: 3` put it as `network_id:'3',` and I think this should start working.

AFAIK the problem is that truffle identifies networks based on network id and it is not able to parse your network_id in a proper way.

Please upvote and accept if it helps. Thanks!!!

Reference: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/reference/configuration

Comment: perfect .. it works for me .. thanks